# Running python py file from cmd but getting ImportError. Running from conda prompt is working

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda, nohup

I'm trying to run a py file in D drive from cmd to make it run in the background.
Command used:

```
nohup python -u D:\project\Telegram_bot\Telegram_bot.py &
```

It is creating ImportError in the nohup.out file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\project\Telegram_bot\Telegram_bot.py", line 11, in <module>
    from telegram.ext.updater import Updater
  File "D:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .updater import Updater
  File "D:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\updater.py", line 22, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "D:\Software\Anaconda\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: The specified module could not be found.
```

Now running the command from conda promt with little change in the nohup command

```
nohup python -u D:\project\Telegram_bot\Telegram_bot.py &
```

This is working as expected but the issue is if I close the conda prompt the file stops executing.

**NOTE:**
Anaconda is installed in my D drive not C drive(primary drive)

Comment: The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` is not a Linux/Mac shell interpreter like `bash`. `nohup` and `&` at end of the command line makes sense only for Linux/Mac shell interpreters in certain use cases, but not for the Windows command processor at all. On Windows is executed `python.exe` with the Python script file as argument.

Comment: Please read the Python documentation pages [Command line and environment](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html), especially the section about the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` with the list of folder paths of the folders containing the modules used by a Python script, [Using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) and [Finding modules](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-modules).

Comment: Ya true I was able to run these commands only after I installed cygwin and thanks for the doc links will go through them and answer my own question if I manage to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the **Anaconda Prompt** does is it adds several folder to your system path: Not just the location of the interpreter, but also the location of the dll libraries.

If you are running from the cmd prompt, you probably just have the interpreter on the path, nothing else. This is why the dll import fails.

You ALWAYS have to activate conda before you have access to the full Anaconda Python installation. See [activating an environment](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment). Note that there is at least the **base** environment.